# Angular 5 jasmine tests, component not compiling

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I'm trying to write a simple unit test, but cannot get my template to compile. The `AppComponent` has one variable called `text` which renders to an `h1` tag. When testing the html, this always comes back as `''`. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

**Test code**

```
import {TestBed, async, ComponentFixture} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let component: AppComponent;
  const mainTitle = 'Angular Unit Testing';

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents()
      .then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
      });
  }));

  it(`should render ${mainTitle} to an H1 tag`, async(() => {
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    console.log('here', compiled.querySelector('h1'));
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toEqual(mainTitle);
  }));

});
```

**Component code**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
  text = 'Angular Unit Testing';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>{{text}}</h1>
```

Comment: will be more easy to answer  if you can bring also code of component

Comment: ok I have added it

Comment: Create your `fixture` ( `TestBed.createComponent()` ) and component instance reference inside each `it()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set "text" public property of component-only then it will be rendered inside h1 tag

```
it(`should render ${mainTitle} to an H1 tag`, async(() => {
  const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
  component.text = 'Angular Unit Testing';
  fixture.detectChanges(); 
  expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toEqual(mainTitle);
}));
```

Comment: Ah ok, this isn't the problem but `fixture.detectChanges` seems to solve the issue. Thanks!